# How to install any rpm file using python script [Python3.6]

Tags: installation, python-3.6, rpm

```
import subprocess
package_path = '/home/mypackage.rpm'
command = ['rpm', '-Ivh', package_path]
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
p.wait()
if p.returncode == 0:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

I am seeing this error while running the above script : Executing command "['/bin/rpm', '--ivh ', '/opt/starter/app_dist/filename.noarch.rpm']" rpm: --ivh : unknown option Something went wrong

Comment: I would recommend _not_ doing this using `subprocess` but instead use the proper python libraries; `dnf` and others are all python-native. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is '-i', not '-I'. And not '--i'. Just '-i'.